# Handled exception go to application error in server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, exception

I have some code that is handled using a `try catch` block, like this:

```
try{
    some code;
} catch(Exception ex){

}
```

In the "some code" line, I am getting an exception caught in the catch block.

But my problem is that the exception is caught in catch block, and also the control moves to an application error event in `global.aspx`.

This problem is only occurring in an application that hosted on our server. While debugging this as a local application, its not happening.

I'd be grateful for a solution to this.

Regards,
Karthik.

Comment: Are you sure your code in catch isn't causing an exception on the server?

Comment: Locally are you running IIS express?  If yes try running it locally in IIS.  It could help you debug the problem if you can the recreate it.

Comment: @artm: yes im sure, code in catch block isn't cause exception

Comment: @cheesesharp How do you set the project to run in IIS, instead of IIS express?

Comment: If you right click the mouse on the project inside visual studio, select properties, then the web tab on the left, from there under the servers section you can change IIS Express to Local IIS.  If you have not activated IIS on your pc please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181052(v=vs.80).aspx